# Python: selecting columns for plotting based on values on rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like

|  | Angle | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wavelength | 20.5 | 677.8 | 445.76 | 345.76 | 987.5 |
| 1 | 56 | 432.56 | 123.65 | 545.76 | 456.65 |
| 2 | 67 | 9568.7 | 456.53 | 564.987 | 5675.4 |
| 3 | 62 | 9568.7 | 456.53 | 564.987 | 5675.4 |
| 5 | 72 | 9568.7 | 456.53 | 564.987 | 5675.4 |

but with 71rows X 2054columns.
I use pandas to import and rename the the columns and row but when I try to use iloc to choose columns for plotting I always end up with errors.

I would like to plot the column 'angle' in the x-axis and for
y I would like to choose a column with a particular wavelength value, say closer to 500 rather than specifying 445.76.

can someone tell me how this would be possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suppose you say 500, and one cloumn is having values `420,400,445` and other column have `1080, 2150, 449` which one will you choose?

Comment: I want to choose the column based on the value of just one row-specifically the row named wavelength. So when I say 500, then I would choose the column  with value 445 in the row of wavelength since it is the closest. Or maybe it is possible to take the min value and the max value and choose the median? I'm not sure this is possible (I'm quite new to python )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.columns
# Index(['index', 'Angle', '1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype='object')


# step1. find row `Wavelength`
cond = df['index'] == 'Wavelength'
row = df[cond].iloc[0, 2:]
# row = df.loc[0, '1':]  # or use iloc -> df.iloc[0, 2:]

# step2. find which colums is closest to 500
cond = abs(row - 500) == abs(row - 500).min()
col = list(row[cond].index)

print(col) # ['2']

# as index is x-axis, col is y-axis
df.set_index('Angle')[col].plot()
```